# Force scaled ticks for color bar

Tags: pgfplots

I have a plot with a `colorbar`, generated by means of the code

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[colorbar,view={0}{90}]
            \addplot3[surf,domain=0:1,y domain=0:1,samples=40,shader=interp] {1e3*(exp(10*(x+y))-1)/(exp(20)-1)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which results in the picture

[image]

for which I want to force the ticks of the `colorbar` to be scaled, like in [image].

In particular, I want ticks from 1 to 10, so that the scaling factor is `10^2`.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `colorbar style={scaled y ticks=base 10:-2}` to the `axis` options.

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[colorbar,view={0}{90},colorbar style={scaled y ticks=base 10:-2}]
            \addplot3[surf,domain=0:1,y domain=0:1,samples=11,shader=interp] {1e3*(exp(10*(x+y))-1)/(exp(20)-1)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```